# Rails 4: render ERB from database into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have stored the content of a `.html.erb` file in the database. I now want to render the ERB data into a string without displaying it. 
I tried

`rendered = render_to_string(:template => MailTemplate.find(1).body)`

but it throws `Missing template`. Does the `render_to_string` method only work with an actual file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell render to use a text string, not a template.

```
rendered = render_to_string(:text => MailTemplate.find(1).body)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render